Why is the scraped HTML different from browser inspected element?
I am currently working on a web scraping project and encountered an issue while scraping data from https://foundersfund.com/portfolio. I managed to retrieve all the links to each company's page successfully. However, upon testing some of these links, I noticed that the output HTML differs from what is shown in the inspect element tool. Consequently, I am unable to retrieve any information.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = { 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }

response = requests.get("https://foundersfund.com/company/figma/", headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

soup

The output is returning this:
Google Colab
I expected to retrieve information about Figma, but instead, I obtained information about SpaceX. Interestingly, when attempting to view pages for other companies, such as https://foundersfund.com/company/spotify/ or https://foundersfund.com/company/airbnb/, I encountered the same issue with SpaceX appearing instead. I have been troubleshooting this for several days and suspect that there may be an issue with the page itself. It seems that when I load the company's page, it briefly displays the SpaceX page before showing the requested company's page.
Could someone please explain what might be happening here?

Its loaded via JS so you wont be able to do this via beatifulsoup

Its dynamically loaded. So its better to use selenium or its request sending API.

Content is loaded / rendered dynamically by JavaScript - Sometimes you can also see it on the page by refreshing it, then spacex is displayed for a short time, because the resource is first loaded and rendered. Only fractions of a second later the actual company information is rendered.
So try to use the api instead for a single company:
https://foundersfund.com/wp-json/wp/v2/company?slug=figma

or for the top 100:
https://foundersfund.com/wp-json/wp/v2/company?per_page=100

Check your browsers dev tools for network traffic, to get an idea of how to find such information.
Example
import requests

headers = { 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }

response = requests.get('https://foundersfund.com/wp-json/wp/v2/company?slug=figma', headers=headers).json()
response

